# Rsyslog messages are truncated, not sent to the correct file

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, syslog, rsyslog

On Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, I'm using the stock rsyslog configuration and added a custom file in /etc/rsyslog.d with the following contents:

```
# cat /etc/rsyslog.d/62-pc 
local3.debug    /var/log/pc/debug.log
local3.*    /var/log/pc/main.log
```

The two referenced files exist and the files and containing directory are readable and writable by the syslog user. Yet, the only place I find the messages is `/var/log/syslog`. `/var/log/pc/main.log` is empty.

In addition, the messages in `/var/log/syslog`.

I've checked that the program from which the messages originate is not the cause of these troubles: the problem also occurs with the `logger` command.

What can be wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your rsylog config have a statement to include/process this directory?

```
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/
```

Or the specific file you wish;

```
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/62-pc
```

Under Red Hat, Rsyslog defaults to including **just files ending in .conf**.  You may need to edit this line under Ubuntu as well.  If your line looks like this, it won't include a file named `62-pc`.

```
$IncludeConfig /etc/rsyslog.d/*.conf
```

Comment: You earned your bounty! Thanks a lot. edit: it will have to wait 24 hours